# Start Activity from Class Loader

Tags: android, classloader

For my application's manifest, I included activities from a separate apk file I placed on the sdcard. I was wondering if I can use a ClassLoader to load the activities found in the separate apk files and start them?

EDIT: 
So my code would look something like this:

```
ClassLoader loader = new DexClassLoader("/sdcard/myapp.apk",  getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), null, AppUI.class.getClassLoader());

Class<?> appClass = loader.loadClass("com.test.myActivity");

Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), appClass);
myIntent.setClassName("com.test", "com.test.myActivity");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

No. The separate apk will have a different security realm. Look at using intents to start other activities beyond your own application.

Comment: I would load the activity from the other apk and use a intent to start it. I added the code I would run to achieve this.